# Google Calendar Embed Event Info

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, google-calendar-api

I can't seem to embed the event info for a public Google calendar event with an iframe.

Looking at the page directly with Firebug it seems to do a lot of 'behinds the scene' stuff on page-load, even if you're logged out of Google.

Here's the code I have:

```
<iframe scrolling="no" height="600" frameborder="0" width="800" style="border: 0" src="https://www.google.com/calendar/render?eid=OWw4aXJjZDg0ajVwZTdkZTdxc3VjM28yam8gc3RhbXB0ZWNoc2VydmljZXNAbQ&sf=true">
```

It has no response in the FireBug net panel from the GET request, however when you go to the site itself it works just fine.

Any ideas or anyone with experience?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same problem. I think it has to do with the cookies and headers it sets to retrieve the content. A header of `x-frame-options: sameorigin` is set, along with `x-cal-session: [long key]`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try getting the url from following these directions:

> Here's how to embed your calendar on your website:
>
> 1. In the calendar list on the left, click the down-arrow next to the
>      calendar you want to embed, and select Calendar settings.
>      (Alternatively, click the Settings link at the bottom of the
>      calendar list, then click the name of the calendar.)
> 2. Copy the iframe code displayed in the Embed This Calendar section.
> 3. Paste this code into your website to embed your calendar.